# Regex with EURO symbol

Tags: php, regex, arrays

I'm using Regex to grab a few prices from a HTML page. I have working strings for both £ and $ but as soon as I change it for Euros and place the currency symbol at the end of the regex string it doesn't seem to work.

Here's my code: `preg_match('/([0-9]+[\.]*[0-9]*)\€/', $totalprice, $value);`

Yet $value returns an empty array.

Thanks!

Comment: Do you save the file **UTF-8 encoded (without BOM)**? There should be a setting in your IDE. Only with the right encoding the _plain_ **€** symbol is saved correctly. Otherwise use `&euro;` as suggested.

Comment: **BTW:** Do spaces occur before the € sign in the source you're crawling? If so, add the `\s` in the regex. E.g. `/(\d+\.*\d*)\s?[€]/siu`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This seems to be an issue with encoding.  If it is acceptable, try using just the currency unicode symbol for the regex.

```
$totalprice = "595,95€";
preg_match('/((?:[0-9]*[.,])?[0-9]+)\p{Sc}/u', $totalprice, $value);
print_r($value);
```

### [phpFiddle](http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/gux-8m3)

Comment: it could also be a html special character `&euro;`

Comment: @MikeBell Check my comment to your question. **In short:** _Your php script needs to be saved UTF-8 encoded._

Comment: If it helps, here's what I'm trying to get: <h1 class="header-title pull-right">XXXX,XX€<br>

Comment: **AHA!** I see a typo in your regex then: `.` is not found, because the source contains `,` as a decimal separator. Adjust your regex accordingly, e.g. `([0-9]+[\.\,]*[0-9]*)\p{Sc}`.

Comment: @DanielGimenez Your answer is fine, I didn't reply to it directly. I should have put _@MikeBell_ in my comment.

Comment: @Jake Aitchison -- you can `html_entity_decode()` the string before using it

Answer (score 2):

Add the `u` modifier to the end of your regex string to tell it to accept unicode characters.

```
preg_match('/([0-9]+[\.]*[0-9]*)\€/u', $totalprice, $value);
                                   ^
                                add this
```

Answer (score 2):

### I'd use this regex:

```
'#(\d+[\.\,]\d*?)\s?[€]#su'
```

I replaced `/` with `#` for readability.

**Parts of the regex explained:**

- `\d`           Matches digits *(equal to [0-9], just shorter)*
- `[\.\,]`   Matches either `.` or `,` as the decimal separator
- `*?`           Makes the * lazy, *so the engine first attempts to skip the previous item, before trying                   permutations with ever increasing matches of the preceding item*[[1]](http://www.regular-expressions.info/reference.html)
- `\s?`         Matches space characters *(? makes it optional)*

**The modifiers mean:**

- `s`   Match all characters, including newlines
- <s>`i`   Match caseless (case-insensitive)</s>
- `u`   Treat pattern strings as UTF-8 *(for the € sign)*

Comment: why would he want the `i` modifier if there's no alpha characters in the pattern?

Comment: If the euro `€` sign is encoded or something like `&euro;` it could be in different cases in the source like e.g. `&Euro;` or `&EURO;`. That's why I included it.

Comment: well fair enough, but your pattern doesn't look for the entity string, just the symbol. (oh, and entities are case sensitive - `&Ouml;` is different to `&ouml;`. I think the Euro symbol has to be all lower case `&euro;`)

Comment: @Spudley You're right. I've created a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/B3n5g/) to check it out with the &EURO; version.